# Amplify CLI commands do not work - M1 Mac

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-amplify, aws-amplify-cli

I installed the Amplify Cli using `npm install -g @aws-amplify/cli` on my M1 Mac.

When I run `amplify` in terminal, nothing happens. A new terminal line just appears. No error, just a new line. Running `amplify help` `amplify -v` `amplify configure` all do nothing.

```
% amplify help
%
```

How do I get the amplify cli to work?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I faced the same issue with my M2. After trying both the NPM and the cURL methods, I realised I needed to install Rosetta first:

```
softwareupdate --install-rosetta
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks. Adding more detail and context to 'softwareupdate --install-rosetta':
https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT211861

"Rosetta is not an app that you open or interact with. Rosetta works automatically in the background whenever you use an app that was built only for Mac computers with an Intel processor. It translates the app for use with Apple silicon."